# Why is it that when I construct a JavaScript Date object with another Date object, the resulting Date object has the ms parts stripped?

Tags: javascript, firefox, datetime

If I run a simple test like this:

new Date(new Date(1050)).valueOf()

instead of getting 1050, I get 1000.  This happens on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Google Chrome and Opera correctly return 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt has your answer, but to track it down in the spec:

1. [§15.9.3.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) says for `new Date(value)` to first call `ToPrimitive(value)`
2. [*ToPrimitive*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) can be called with a hint of either number or string. If no hint is provided, the default is number **except** for Date objects, where the hint defaults to *string*.
3. So *ToPrimitive* calls the object's *toString* method, which in this case is [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2), which returns an implementation dependent string representing the date.
4. This string is then parsed by [*Date.parse*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), which is also implementation dependent for non–standard strings, which converts the string to a date object.

It's during either the *toString* or *parse* steps that the milliseconds get dropped. However I can't imagine a reason to convert a time value to a string, then back to a time value in the one expression.

Note that this parsing means that something like `new Date('5/5/70')` will create a date object for 5 May 1970, even if the year 70AD was required. So if you are copying date objets using `new Date(dateObject)`, it's a good idea to do `new Date(+dateObject)` to coerce the date to its [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) rather than let ECMA-262 have its way and use the string value. Though it's extremely unlikely that you'll need to copy dates in the range 0 to 99AD, it's nice to know it will work correctly if attempted.

Comment: Nice find.  ECMAScript is one of my *least* favorite specs. I don't think I could have found that one.

Comment: You are right that it is unlikely that someone needs this.   I discovered this because of a bug in the code where the variable being passed into to a function was sometimes a Date but other times a string.   So once the bug was discovered, we make sure to not construct a new Date() object if the parameter is already a date.

Comment: By the way, if you're curious, the reason this happened is because we assumed that JSON.parse would return an object of the right type.  For example, this works correctly for numbers.   The following would return the string "number" --> typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Number(1000)))
 . . . . . However, the following returns 'string' which is sucky 'cause it really just as easily have returned a date --> typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date(1000)))

Comment: Rob,  very clear.  I had no idea that that level of detail was in the ECMAScript spec..  Now that i know, I'll consult there first.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the inner date is being converted to a string, then parsed by the constructor of the outer date.

Note that in all browsers:

```
new Date(new Date(1050).toString()).valueOf()
```

returns 1000, while:

```
new Date(new Date(1050).valueOf()).valueOf()
```

returns 1050.

The output of `toString` simply doesn't contain any millisecond information.

Perhaps someone else can answer as to *why* some browsers use `toString` instead of `valueOf` in these sort of "implicit conversion" scenarios.  My guess is that the behavior is undefined in the ECMAScript specification - but I haven't checked.

Comment: Not "likely" but per [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2). :-) A consequence is that dates like "21-Feb-29" (i.e. date where 0 < year < 100) are converted to dates in the 20th century (21-Feb-1929 in this case) in some browsers (IE and Safari at least). So `Date.parse` doesn't necessarily correctly parse even its own stringified date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new Date(new Date(1050).getTime()).getTime()
```

That will get the same result of '1050' in all browsers.

Comment: Or `new Date(+new Date(1050))` for what it's worth. But that doesn't answer the question "why".

Comment: my example was to demonstrate the difference between the browsers.   By doing getTime() (or valueOf()) on the inner Date object before passing it in to the outer Date object's constructor defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to demonstrate, which is to show that passing in a Date object to the constructor of a Date object has subtly different behavior on different browsers.  I prefer RobG's answer..